# Servlet Filters - Context Initialization

Tags: java, tomcat, synchronization, servlet-filters

When using a "global" filter, one which is located in the root lib directory of an apache tomcat webserver and applies to all web application contexts: 
I was wondering if the web application contexts are initialized synchronously - one at a time, or can there be a case where the Filter.init() function is called by two different contexts in the same time.

I'm asking this since I want to initialize a database connection configuration object based on a specific FilterConfig.initParameter the first time init() is called by any of the application contexts, and I'm wondering if I should put the above in a synchronized block or not...

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the internals of Tomcat, it could change any time so I'd do it in a synchronized block. It's not a big deal or performance issue because it runs only once per application context initialization.

From [Java Servlet Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-mrel-eval-oth-JSpec/) *6.2.1 Filter Lifecycle*:

> Only one instance per <filter> declaration in the deployment
>   descriptor is instantiated per JVM of the container.

You could reach the same result with a custom Valve:

- [The Valve Component](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html)
- [Valve javadoc](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/Valve.html)